# Inverse Transform Function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, preprocessor

I am implementing an LSTM code in python. I did a preprocessing step to my raw training data to scale it between -1 and 1 as following:

```
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
np_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(np_scaled)
```

After making prediction for the test data, I got results scaled between -1 and 1.

The question is: How can I reverse this transformation step to get results look like the initial data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform)

```
original = min_max_scaler.inverse_transform(np_scaled)
```